# Send and get data from SoftLayer object storage using libcurl

Tags: get, libcurl, put, cloud-storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am new to libcurl and all the cloud technology.

I need to store and retrieve 1024 byte objects in the cloud as objects where each object has 2 properties the file name and an id.

Can someone please guide me how to solve this problem or just give me an example in C so that I will be able to understand this whole procedure.

Now I can not even figure out how to authenticate with SoftLayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation, it contains information about how to authenticate and upload files using Curl:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/Managing-SoftLayer-Object-Storage-Through-REST-APIs

As you can see to work with Softlayer Object Storage you only need to execute some simple HTTP GET and Post requests. You can see examples about how to do that using libcurl here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

If you need more documentation about Softlayer object storage see:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/objectstorageapi

I hope it helps

Regards